# Godaddy email server and website hosted on GCP (c# application), Emails not working - getting timeout issue

Tags: asp.net, email, google-cloud-platform

I have a email purchased from Godaddy and a website developed in .net is hosted on GCP app Engine. Emails were working fine before and now getting timed out. It is still working fine from local host but on cloud emails stopped working. Please help.

Comment: Seems like godaddy blocking my IP as i am directly using SMTP from my code. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You may need to contact them to open alternative port.